# How to play audio lists dynamically with Ionic4 Native audio

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

I want to play a list of audio files just after its predecessor is played in an ionic4 project with angular/typescript.

I am able to play the audios manually like this

```
PlayList(){

      this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1', () => {

           //the first audio is done playing
              this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId2', () => {
                 //the second video is done playing 
                         this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId3', () => {


                                                      }

                                           }

              }

     }
```

I tried to play it within a loop with async/ await but they are all playing at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve through a help.

```
 playOne(track: string): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(resolve => this.nativeAudio.play(track, resolve));
}

playAll(tracks: string[]): void {
  let player = (acc, track) => acc.then(() => this.playOne(track));
  tracks.reduce(player, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Array.reduce allows us to feed the results of one iteration into the next. Each successive run waits on the last one and returns a new Promise on which the next will wait.

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Hi @kplus, Have you tried my solution? I edited yesterday with dynamically content.

Comment: Yes, I did, it did not work for me. The answer I gave was the one that worked form . It was suggested by ionic moderator in ionic forum. Thank you so much for the effort though

Comment: Oh, I thaught it would work.. anyway, glad you could solve it!

Answer (score 0):

I assume `nativeAudio.play()` is a `promise`. With your code you are not waiting to end the first method to call the second because the promise is not completed. You can do it chaining the promises or well with `async/await` way.

Like:

```
async PlayList(){
 await this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1);
 await this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId2);
 await this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId3);
}
```

Dynamically, I would do it like:

```
async PlayList(){
 const listIds = ['uniqueId1', 'uniqueId2', 'uniqueId3'];
 await Promise.all(listIds.map(async id => await this.nativeAudio.play(id));
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: how would you do this dynamically, I am able to play all the audio files with desired result writing manual codes.

Comment: I edited the question and added the dynamically way.